# Scanner cannot read (int) data from textfile with numbers - Java Highscore System (LWJGL)

Tags: issue-tracking

Cannot find the issue, as you can see in the method "readFile", I've tried to see if the problem is that the scanner reads a string, but when I compile the program it'll say the textfile's name, scores.txt, and not the content. Been working on this for about 3 hours, dayum.

```
package pointSystem;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

import main.Gooftw;

public class HighscoreManager {

    private int currentHighScores[] = new int[5];
    private int newScore = Gooftw.getScore();
    private int temp;

    //private Formatter formatter;
    private Scanner sc;
    private String file = "scores.txt";
    File outfile;
    FileOutputStream fop = null;

    public HighscoreManager () {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        try {
            //formatter = new Formatter(file);

            sc = new Scanner(file);

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("you have an error");
        }

        //Read current highscores to game

    }

    public void readFile(){
        int i = 0;
        String values [] = new String [5];
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            values[i] = sc.next();
            System.out.println(values[i]);
            /*System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
            currentHighScores[i] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(currentHighScores[i]);*/
            i++;
        }

        this.closeFile();

        /*for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
            System.out.println(currentHighScores[i]);       
        }
        /*while(sc.hasNext()){
            String a = sc.next();
            String b = sc.next();
            String c = sc.next();

            System.out.printf(a,b,c);
        }*/
    }

    public void addRecords(){

        try{
        outfile = new File(file);
        fop = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

        if(!outfile.exists()){
            outfile.createNewFile();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            //formatter.format("%s \n", currentHighScores[i] );
            fop.write(currentHighScores[i] );

        }
        //fop.flush();
        fop.close();

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try{
                if(fop!=null){
                    fop.close();
                }

                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        //formatter.close();



    public void compareScores(){

        if(newScore > currentHighScores[0]){
            temp = currentHighScores[0];
            currentHighScores[0] = newScore;
        }
        for(int y = 1 ; y<5 ; y++){
            if(temp < currentHighScores[y]){

                temp = temp + currentHighScores[y];
                currentHighScores[y] = temp - currentHighScores[y];
                temp = temp - currentHighScores[y];
            }
        }

    }

    public void closeFile(){
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the name of the file rather than the file because you pass the string that is the name of the file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)

*public Scanner(String source)
Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string.
Parameters:
source - A string to scan*

You want this constructor instead:

*public Scanner(InputStream source,
               String charsetName)
Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified input stream. Bytes from the stream are converted into characters using the specified charset.*

Make a file input stream using this constructor:

*public FileInputStream(String name)
                throws FileNotFoundException
Creates a FileInputStream by opening a connection to an actual file, the file named by the path name name in the file system.*

And pass THAT to the scanner.

What did we learn today? Don't assume what a method or constructor does if you haven't read its documentation. Following this simple rule will save you a lot of time.